# I want to add a new Object inside a Json Object in JAVA with JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Im trying to make a JAVA application that makes a json file with the data that i send, but when i send new data, the last data the data is just replaced

the first method called

```
az.addUser("John", "10", "star");
```

the JSON

```
{
   "user" : {
       "name": "john",
       "score": "10",
       "type": "star"
   }
}
```

second method called

```
az.addUser("Kevin", "20", "energy");
```

The JSON Expected

```
{
    "user" : {
       "name": "john",
       "score": "10",
       "type": "star"
   }

    "user" : {
        "name" = "Kevin",
        "score" = "20",
        "type" = "energy"
    }
}
```

the REAL JSON

```
{  
    "user" : {
        "name" = "Kevin",
        "score" = "20",
        "type" = "Energy"
    }
}
```

The Method

```
public void addUser(String name, String score, String type){
    FileWriter wf = new FileWriter("exit.json");
    JSONObject json;
    JSONObject jsonInternal = new JSONObject();

    jsonInternal.put("name", name);
    jsonInternal.put("score", score);
    jsonInternal.put("type", type);

    json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("user", jsonInternal);
    wf.write(json.toJSONString());
    wf.close();

}
```

Comment: Your expected JSON has duplicate keys... Did you want an array of users instead?

Comment: Btw, you are  **overriding** the same file on every `addUser` call

Comment: i dont need the "user", i just put to ilustrate

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a JSON array, not a JSON object. The code below is strictly pseudocode, as I do not know which library `JSONObject` comes from.

```java
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UserListWriter {
    private String filename;
    private JSONArray usersJson;

    public UserListWriter(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.usersJson = new JSONArray();
    }

    public UserListWriter addUser(String name, int score, String type) {
        JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject();
        userJson.put("name", name);
        userJson.put("score", score);
        userJson.put("type", type);
        usersJson.put(userJson);
        return this;
    }
    
    public UserListWriter write() throws IOException {
        FileWriter wf = new FileWriter(this.filename);
        wf.write(usersJson.toJSONString());
        wf.close();
        return this;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new UserListWriter("exit.json")
                .addUser("John", 10, "star")
                .addUser("Kevin", 20, "energy")
                .write();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretical output:

```json
[{
  "name": "John",
  "score": 10,
  "type": "star"
}, {
  "name": "Kevin",
  "score": 20,
  "type": "energy"
}]
```

Comment: write method could be void, no?

Comment: didnt work, always replace the json